# Page viewer Webpart Full page

Tags: page-viewer-web-part, dialog-framework

Is it possible to Config Weppart page viewer to view web page not as a frame but as normal page? 
Unfortunately,. this page has some scripts that changes its layout to mobile version if the detect page its into a frame or the web browser is resized.
I've been trying to give it large pixel layout but no way!

[Example link](http://www.camparigroup.com/en/investor/share-performance)